# After waking up, what must I eat/drink if I want to have a workout asap

Tags: bodybuilding, nutrition, health, meal-plan, breakfast

After waking up, I want to go gym directly.

However I have an empty stocmach to workout, I know that causes my body to use protein as fuel.

If I have breakfast, then I have to wait 2-3 hours and I don't want to wait.

So what should I eat/drink so that I can go do gym directly, and my workout.

**P.S:** My workout doesn't include any cardio, so my blood suger won't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Water should be your top priority and your priorities after that might include a preworkout (or simply caffeine) and/or a small bite to eat such as a fruit.

If you are working out shortly after waking up, your body should still be full (or mostly full) on glycogen from the night before unless you did some intense activity after your last meal. Your body will use that glycogen as well as fat as fuel during your training session. It doesn’t seem entirely unlikely that protein may also be used, but it hardly seems justified to assume that most or even a notable portion of the energy requirements would come from it. Instead, you are likely looking at negligible losses. Unless of course your workouts are ridiculously long, >1.5 hours. Even then, it’s going to be less about fuel source and more about your capacity to keep going and actually have a productive training session.

I’m not sure why you are bringing up blood sugar, but I’ll address it anyway. If you have no problems with blood sugar, working out on an empty stomach won’t cause problems with that. However, if you do have such problems you might be endangering yourself and you should reconsider. Speak to a medical professional.

Comment: +1: my go to is to chug some water when I wake up and then coffee and a banana on the way to the gym.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. However, people are not really united on what you should eat before training in general. Even if mankind would come to an agreement on this topic, it would still be workout specific. From your question, it seems that you have two concerns (correct me if I am wrong):

- you are unable to eat a short time before a workout
- you are afraid that your body will not handle workout in a good way only with nutrients from the previous day

In this case, I would approach it via testing what will work for me, for example in this order:

1. small portion food (yogurt, rice... whatever you consider important before training in general - this is again more "religion" related question). If this does not feel good, then:
2. protein shake (or a protein shake with something extra - for example honey). If this is still too much:
3. BCAA in any form or any other nutrients in pills

I guess some people would suggest using some stimulants like caffeine. However, if you sleep and rest enough, there should not be a need for such a "cheating" at all.

Note: If you ask 10 different people how to tackle this problem, you probably get 10 different answers. And they all can be wrong (or good).